# Woocommerce : How to automatically input the same email for every order?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use wordpress and woocommerce to sell online courses. also I use "digits" plugin to make users able to order and create accounts using only their mobile phone numbers and therefore, email is not needed and I have removed email field from checkout using "checkout filed editor" plugin.

But woocommerce creates download links based on user emails, therefore download links are invalid for users after they buy something and want to download it. because of that, I have to manually add an email like "orders@example.com" to every order and revoke download links of that order to make download links work.

---

**the question is :** how to automatically add "orders@example.com" to email field of every order when users order something?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to change that value? or is it fixed no matter what?

Comment: A fixed and constant value no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achive that you only need two woocommerce filters.

First we remove the email post field from the checkout form.

Second we set the the submited form data, email, to some fixed value.

This is the whole code, paste it into `functions.php` and you are good to go. Don't forget to change the email to what ever you need.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'bt_manipulate_checkout_fields');
function bt_manipulate_checkout_fields ($fields) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);

    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_posted_data', 'bt_manipulate_checkout_posted_data');
function bt_manipulate_checkout_posted_data ($data) {
    $data['billing_email'] = 'orders@example.com';

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Since I already removed email field using checkout fields editor plugin, I only used second filter and it happily solved this issue in my case. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Erfan Glad I could help, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you

Comment: I've newly created my account so still cant upvote an answer but gladly I accepted the answer :)